# class-transformer TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: typescript, json-deserialization, class-transformer

I am using `class-transformer` in my typescript code base to transform a deserialized "plain" object into a specific Typescript instance type. But it does not seem to be working as expected as method invocations on the transformed object throws the error about method being undefined `TypeError: undefined is not a function`.

When I call `getAs24Hour()` or `toString()` method on the transformed object i get the `undefined is not a function` error. I am using `plainToInstance(BasicTime, jsonObj as BasicTime)` function to transform the plain object.

I followed the code example from the library but seems I must be missing some thing here?

```
export class Hour {
    hour: number
    isAm: boolean

    constructor(hour: number, isAm: boolean) {
        if (hour < 0 || hour > 11) {
            throw new Error("Hour should be between 0 and 11 inclusive.")
        }

        this.hour = hour
        this.isAm = isAm
    }

    getAs24Hour(): number {
        return this.isAm ? this.hour : this.hour + 12
    }

    toString(): string {
        return this.hour < 10 ? `0${this.hour.toString()}` : this.hour.toString()
    }
}


export class BasicTime {
    @Type(() => Hour)
    hour: Hour;

    @Type(() => Minute)
    min: Minute;

    constructor(hour: Hour, min: Minute) {
        this.hour = hour
        this.min = min
    }
}
```

// assuming i get the json from a datastore I do the following to transform

```
let plain = JSON.parse(jsonString)
let time = plainToInstance(BasicTime, plain as BasicTime)
time.hour.getAs24Hour() // fails with error that function is undefined
```

**Edit**: When transforming Hour object directly method invocation works, but when transforming an wrapping object the method invocation on hour fails.

**Update**: Seems like a bug in the library.. https://github.com/typestack/class-transformer/issues/876

Comment: Can you share more how you declare it? ``` CurrentHour = new Hour(12, false); ```

Comment: Thanks. Have added more context. If transforming `Hour` directly the invocation works. But if transforming a enclosing object json and I invoke the method on the hour property of the outer object i get the error.